# Вантажність чи везучисть?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Коли мова йде про здатність транспорту підіймати певну кількість вантажу, зазвичай вживаємо слово *вантажність*. В Словнику українсько-російському 1927р. (А. Ніковський) маємо такий варіант:

> **Везу́чисть** – грузопод’емность (лошади, грузовика).

Чи це слово можна вживати як синонім до *вантажність*, чи є відмінність у значенні і сфері застосування?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наведений Вами приклад визначення [везучить](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)  із Словника українсько-російського 1927р. (А. Ніковський)  російське слово, не українське.

"Везучисть" не може бути синонімом слова "вантажність".

В українській мові використовуються такі слова, для характеристики здатності транспорту до перевезення вантажу: ***вантажність, вантажопідйомність, вантажопідіймальність***

З СУМ-20

> **[Вантажність](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6609&page=241)** Те саме, що ***вантажопідйо́мність.*** *Для повнішого
> використання вантажності автомашин треба нарощувати їх кузови і
> використати всі наявні автопричепи* (з наук. літ.)
>
> **[Вантажопідйомність](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6618&page=242)** Те саме, що ***вантажопідійма́льність.*** *Кран
> вантажопідйомністю до 200 т.*
> **[Вантажопідіймальність](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=138594&page=242)** **Максимальна
> вага вантажу, на яку розрахований піднімальний механізм.** *У першому
> розділі праці подано показники потужності та вантажопідіймальності
> навантажувачів у кожній із вагових груп* (з наук. літ.);
> **// Найбільше
> корисне навантаження, на яке розрахований автомобіль, вагон, судно,
> літак.** *Збільшився потік вугілля з лав. Це примусило насамперед
> подумати про підвищення вантажопідіймальності підземного транспорту*
> (з наук.-попул. літ.); *Залежно від вантажопідіймальності вантажні
> автомобілі поділяють на три класи* (з навч. літ.);
> **//Найбільший
> вантаж, який кінь може зрушити з місця і везти.** *Тренований молодняк
> випробовувався не лише на максимальну вантажопідіймальність, а й на
> витривалість та швидке підвезення вантажів* (із журн.).

Comment: Наведене у запитанні посилання на статтю зі словника Ніковського — якраз про **українське** слово «везучисть» (якому відповідає російське «грузопод’емность (лошади, грузовика)»). Інша справа, що те слово згадується лише в одному зі словнику тих часів, тобто, мабуть, є не лише застарілим станом на наш час, а й було рідковживаним навіть у 1920-і.

Comment: (А сучасні словники фіксують лише **розмовний** прикметник «[везучий](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7221&page=266)» (зокрема в значенні «який добре везе (перевозить, пересуває)»), але не іменник «везуч{и/і}сть» — це вже не заперечення до Вашої відповіді, а просто невеличке доповнення.)

Comment: @Sasha Дякую за доповнення.

Comment: Власне, найважливішою частиною моїх коментарів було саме заперечення, а не доповнення (заперечення до тієї частини, де Ви казали, що «везучисть» начебто рос., а не укр. слово — за словником Ніковського це саме укр. слово (хоча, звісно, це може бути й помилкою Ніковського)).